# Win10 USBSER Device Hardware Descriptors

Tags: usb, windows-10, libusb, wdk, usbserial

I'm using USB Class02/SubClass02 on my embedded device to make use of the Windows10 build in USB COM port drivers (usbser.sys / mdmcpq.inf).
My device provides manufacturer/device descriptors, but i have found that Win10 does not seem to use them as a title for the device in device manager and in other locations. Instead its just listed as a "USB Serial Device (COM?)" and the manufacturer as being Microsoft.

Does anyone know if there is a way of the device (via flags or similar) instructing Win10 (and drivers) to use the device provided names instead?
Or is the only way to do this by providing a INF only device driver with the strings?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Or is the only way to do this by providing a INF only device driver with the strings?

Windows uses the INF file for the device title only. Thus you would have to supply an INF file.